# Corporate PKI - is it an enterprise standard?

Tags: tls

I've heard from one person that companies often issue own certificate for their internal usage. It's not signed by any public CA. And he says that it's an enterprise standard. I couldn't find any proof for that on the Internet and thus here is my question - is that really an Enterprise standard and what are the benefits of having such certificates? I could find only drawbacks.

Comment: Define "Enterprise Standard" - I think your question may be tautological.

Comment: While "standard" is debatable, to get at your real question, yes, it is very common for large enterprise to have private CAs and install their own root certs in the trust stores on all of the company's machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *self-signed* certificate is considered a certificate signed by the key inside the certificate itself. This is not common for larger installations (i.e. companies) because it does not scale, i.e. you would need to have exceptions or certificate pinning for each issued certificate.

What was probably meant is that a company has their own PKI structure with their own internal root-CA and use it to sign their own certificates. In this case it is enough that each system only trusts the company's root CA in order to verify each certificate issued by the company. This setup is actually very common in larger companies because it scales well. But even if these certificates are signed by the company *themselves* their are *not* called self-signed certificates, because this phrase has already a different meaning.

Comment: You're completely right - they have their own PKI structure. But while their root cert can be spread via Windows Group Policies, that doesn't include software like Java, NodeJS and alike. And given it takes a lot of efforts to add cert into all the software, I still can't understand the benefits of having own PKI.

Comment: It's really not that bad.  Most companies will use this for remote network access through a VPN, or to access intranet type servers.  It can also make secure email communication much easier.  Installing the certificates on a server for your webapps to use is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Installing certs is easy. Adding them to a trusted store of every version of every app on every machine - that's a challenge :)

Answer (score 2):

First, a ***standard*** is a set of actions or rules that an organization can set that generally support a policy - like an Information Security Policy.

How self-signed certificates are used in an enterprise can be dictated in a *standard* but there is no industry standard that I know of that talks about self-signed certificates. Instead there are best-practices which can generally be followed but might not be "best" for some organizations. In other words, if there is an Enterprise Standard on the use of self-signed certificates it would apply to that enterprise that wrote the standard.

I referenced ISO 27002 and did not find anything specific about self-signed certificates.

If we are talking about self-signed certificates on an Internet facing, company, production web server that requires HTTPS then a self-signed certificate would probably be a bad choice. If we are talking about that same server that's in a developer's test environment then it's probably okay.

Self-signed certificates are generated in many scenarios within an enterprise LAN but unless it is an Internet facing web server they are usually fine.

Answer (score 2):

In hierarchical PKI structures root certificates are self-signed by definition. In enterprise you may have your own company root installed in trust store(s) of every device in the company, and it will be as good as any other trust anchor, then.

Main benefit of having your own PKI is that you may limit your services to accept certificate chain only from your own CA (either root or dedicated intermediate), and no 3rd party will be able to forge it easily (see the MCS Holdings case, this year) - like the HPKP, but without TOFU problem ;).

Another important thing is that for services that can't be accessible from outside (for example host in domain that exists only in your internal network) you simply have to use your own PKI, because public CA won't be able to perform validation.

When you run internal PKI you also won't have to pay for every single host certificate. Alternative solution from public CA is either to use wildcard certificates for multiple hosts (not really safe - one breach and all hosts are compromised), or pay for every single host certificate.

What's important, though, is that company internal PKI should be properly managed and strictly controlled, according to the standards like [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements Certificate Policy for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) and/or [Mozilla CA Certificate Policy](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/policy/). You'll probably learn RFC 5280 and RFC 6960 in the process, as well.

Main drawback I can see is that your root CA won't be trusted by 3rd party, and that's the only case when you really need certificate issued by public CA - services that need to be accessible in the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

A certificate provides you (generally speaking) a few things:

- a way to ensure confidentiality of the communication by setting up an encrypted tunnel
- a way for your client application (a web browser for instance) to ensure that the server is actually the one you want to connect to (there is also the possibility to check the other way round)

A self-signed certificate will correctly fulfill the first need (encryption). It won't be better or worse than a certificate provided by a PKI.

Since this is a self-signed certificate, you do not have any means to ensure that it is a trusted one (every server can have one). This may or may not be a problem for you. If it is then it must be *signed* by a third party you both trust (called the Certificate Authority, CA in short). This CA can be internal to the company or external. What needs to be ensured is that it is known of the clients (browsers in the case above). This is the case for major commercial CAs and needs to be specifically configured for browsers using an internal PKI.